# Chromium will not start,

Tags: chromium

I did an ubuntu upgrade this morning and when I reboot the machine, chromium-browser will not run.  I purged it with sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser and reinstalled it with sudo apt-get install chromium-browser.

When I try to run it from a terminal I get a message like:
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[22032:22032:1214/132224.411454:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.

The command hangs and I have to ctrl-c to get the shell back. 
No chromium processes are running when it is done.

If while the command is hung I get and I check for processes I see 5

```
1) --enable-pinc
2) --type=zygote
1) --type=gpu-process -- field-trial-handle=somelongnumber --gpu-preference=KAA...
1) --type=-broker
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:
I decided on a whim to run sudo chromium-browser, got an error message about not using the option --no-sandbox.  I ran with sudo chromium-browser --no-sandbox and it seemed to work, I got a dialog that said "Profile error occured"  Your preferences could not be read?

I then pinned the browser to the Launcher and it runs without sudo but I always get the "Profile error occured " dialog.  It won't save preferences, and some features are unavailable.

Comment: One recent answer quoted workaround for Ubuntu 14.04 and Chromium 53, but the question does not have such information. Consider to edit your question and include: 1. Which release of Ubuntu? 2. Which version of Chromium browser?

Answer (score 0):

From [this bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1563184), there is one suggestion found in the comments.

Henry Wertz (hwertz10) wrote on 2016-11-04:

> [...] I have an Acer Chromebook 13 (Tegra K1) which had 14.04 on it; Chromium 52 or 53 worked fine. Went to 16.04 (managing to hold back X so I could keep the nvidia driver...) and chromium blew up as others have reported.
>
> I also found the 14.04 build of (at this point, chromium 53) worked
>   fine after I set "--disable-namespace-sandbox"... I had the "Aw,
>   snap!" but found (per google) that "--disable-namespace-sandbox" fixed
>   it without the ill effects of "--no-sandbox".